# Can i add the same URL Link top Link and Quick launch in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I need to make some kind of functionality that when the user clicks on the Top link and Quick launch 2013 same page should open.

I have dragged and dropped documents from site content to quick launch to add some URL Link there and its working fine and landing on some page.

I want the same page URl to be there on the top link so that both will redirect to the same page.

Can it be possible to copy one's URL and put it in edit link option so that both will redirect me to the same page?

Answer (score 1):

You can set these links in Navigation section.

Go to **Site Settings** >> Click on **Navigation**.

In that section, you can set these links in Global Navigation and Current Navigation to see that links in both Top Link and Quick Launch.
[image]

Comment: This I can do to edit the quick launch.What about the top link can I add the same link here so that the top link and the Quick Launch link will open the redirected URL.

Comment: For Top Link bar, You can add same link in Global Navigation (as shown in image). After adding link in global navigation, you can see that link in top bar.